# Laravel check if Request has collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to run an if statement over each of my posted requests and if any are a collection do something different.

When I die dump `$request->all` I have an array that looks like this;

```
  "_token" => "MMRFBAgyThsIHzITzT26Qwdp4L6HDV0JTPGs6h"
  "page_name" => "Travel"
  "heading" => "Travel Europe"
  "textarea" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru ▶"
  "seo_title" => "travel"
  "seo_description" => "travel"
  "attribute_1" => "Food"
  "attribute_2" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor."
  "attribute_3" => "Hotels"
  "attribute_6" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor."
  "attribute_5" => "Events"
  "attribute_4" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor."
  "attribute_7" => null
  "attribute_8" => null
  "attribute_9" => UploadedFile {#233 ▶}
```

The data will be different so I can't write anything static e.g.`$request->input('attribute_9')`

This is how I'm currently handling the attributes which are the unknown requests.

```
$input = $request->all();

foreach($input as $key=>$value) {

    if(strstr($key,'attribute_')) {
        $i = str_replace("attribute_", "", $key);


        if (!empty($value)) {   
            if ($value instanceof Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile) {
                dd('lets have a collection...');
            }

            Attribute::where('id', $i)->update(['value' => $value]);
        } else{
            Attribute::where('id', $i)->update(['value' => '']);
        }

    }
}
```

You can see I've tried to check the `$value` using `instanceOf` but that hasn't worked. The if statement is never true and the page just returns.

Example of attribute input submission -

```
@if($comp_attr['data_type'] == 'file')
   <div class="form-grp img-form" style="width: {{ $comp_attr['width'] }}%;">
    <label>Banner Image</label>
        <span class="img-hold">
            {{ $banner }}
        </span>
    <input type="{{ $comp_attr['field_type'] }}" name="attribute_{{ $comp_attr['id'] }}" />
   </div>
@else
    <div class="form-grp" style="width: {{ $comp_attr['width'] }}%;">
        <label>{{ $comp_attr['label'] }}</label>
        <input type="{{ $comp_attr['field_type'] }}" name="attribute_{{ $comp_attr['id'] }}" value="{{ $comp_attr['value'] }}" />
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Could you also paste a snippet of your frontend form and the code that handles the posting to the server?

Comment: The form is too big to post but I can show you an example of how the attributes are posted. Updated original post.

Comment: Sweet, i have added an answer that should fit the use case derived from the added examples :)

Comment: It won't be an instance of UploadedFile unless you call the `$request->file('field_name')` function on the field. An easier way than comparing with instance of is likely `$request->hasFile('field_name')`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are trying to get the `$_FILES`

So you can get all the files using

```
$request->allFiles();
```

This will return you all the files in the request. then you can perform any action on it.

Hope this helps

Comment: > "The data will be different so I can't write anything static"

Comment: I mean the input names will always be different so I can't write a static request based on an input name. I do need to be able to tell if the posted request is a file. Becuase I loop over all of the requests can you do an is not file to skip?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`name="attribute_{{ $comp_attr['id'] }}"`

Try

`name="attributes[{{ $comp_attr['id'] }}]"`

Notice the new 's' ^ , and the brackets on either side of the `{{ }}`

By using brackets we convert it to an associative array, keyed by the blade variable.

Then on the php side you can do something like this:

```
foreach($request->get('attributes') as $i => $value)
{
     ...
}
```